# Rewriting URL's for a custom Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the URL:

```
/community-videos/?builder=20
```

**to**

```
/community-videos/builder-name
```

The Builder Name is not stored in the database, so I believe I have to manually set the builder name in the .htaccess, unless I'm mistaken.

I tried the following, but no results:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} builder=20$
RewriteRule (.*) /community-videos/builder-name? [R=301,L]
```

I'm a bit lost, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there other links that are to be rewritten or just that one?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed your Permalink settings? Using the Custom Structure option you can use a post's slug or some other data to create the URL. It seems like the "Post name" option may be what you're looking for. Log into WordPress and go to Settings > Permalinks. And be sure to remove that stuff from your .htaccess.

See this page for the possible tags you can use to structure your URLs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks